# Alternative Jersey Android

Tags: android, jersey

Are there alternatives to Jersey 1.8 that offer converting XML files to java.util.List?  In my web service lists are converted to XML and then sent to the client.

The problem with Jersey is that converting XML files will not work because Android different folders ignored in the libraries.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many XML responses with different structures, you could just create a method that parses the XML for example with XPath or Java DOM. You can also take a look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) which is a great alternative to JAXB.

If you don't have to stick to XML, you can also switch to JSON: [JSON Support - Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.8/json.html) . I've personally found Jackson to be simplier than other solutions.